# Interface структуры, ошибка с ссылками в методах структуры

Tags: golang, интерфейс, link

Хочется создать интерфейс что бы абстрагироваться от структур. Методы структур выполняли действия и присваивали значения своим переменным потом маршалить и отправлять куда нужно. НО! Читаю и пишут что структуры с их методами имеющие ссылку(`func (a *Am)GetL()`), а не объект структуры в методе(`func (a Am)GetL()`) данной структуры не могут быть присвоены интерфейсу. Это не решаемо?

```
package main

import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    var a Style
    a = Am{1}

    Methods(a)
    as,err := json.Marshal(a)
    if err==nil{
        println(string(as))
    }
    if err!=nil{
        println(err.Error())
    }

}

func Methods(in Style) {
    println("Hellow", in.GetL())
    in.SetL(4)
    println("Hellow", in.GetL())
}

type Am struct {
    L int
}

func (a *Am)GetL()int{
    return a.L
}

func (a *Am)SetL(i int){
    a.L = i
}

type Style interface {
    GetL()int
    SetL(i int)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте в интерфейс указатель на структуру:

```
var a Style
a = &Am{1}
```

Comment: Это прекрасно) Спасибо